# python error "unknown option "1": must be moveto or scroll" tkinter canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a image viewing program using tkinter, everything works fine except: I want to have a list of all the images in the directory the user chose, this list should be displayed on a canvas, with a horizontal scrollbar attached to it, I've seen other people on this page had kind of the same problem and someone said to use a frame, that works but when I want to use the scrollbar, I get the following error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in/  
        __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1549, in xview
        res = self.tk.call(self._w, 'xview', *args)
    _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "1": must be moveto or scroll
    >>>
```

I can't make head or tail out of that, so please, any help appreciated, here is the actual code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image,ImageTk
    import os
    import time

    #next image
    def Next():
        i += 1
        global img,i
        print(i)

        display_images(data[i])
        

    #previous image
    def Previous():
        i -= 1
        global img,i
        print(i)

        display_images(data[i])
    #list of images on canvas
    def show_images():
        global photoButtons,imgFile,imOpen,imgFoto,resized,photolist
        j = 0
        for number in data:
            print(">>>",number)
            imOpen.append(Image.open(data[j]))
            imgFile.append(imOpen[j])
            resized.append(imgFile[j].resize((50,50),Image.ANTIALIAS))
            imgFoto.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized[j]))
            photoButtons.append(Button(photolist, text=j,/
            image=imgFoto[j],command=display_images(data[j]),width=50,/
            height = 50))
            photoButtons[j].pack(side=RIGHT)
            j += 1    

    #display selected image
    def display_images(image_name):
        img = Image.open(image_name)
        size = img.resize((700,500),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photoviewer.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(size)
        photoviewer.create_image(0,0, image=photoviewer.image,anchor='nw')

    # END DEF's

    global i

    i=0
    #root
    root = Tk()

    #root size
    root.geometry("1000x720+0+0")
    #canvas for displaying image
    photoviewer = Canvas(root, width=700, height=500)
    photoviewer.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    photoviewer.place(x=295, y=215,)
    #frame (ive got this from another page of stack overflow)
    frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
    #canvas for displaying list of images
    photolist = Canvas(frame, width=395, height=50)
    #scrollbar
    scrl=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrl.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
    scrl.config(command=photolist.xview)
    photolist.pack(side=TOP)

    imgFile = []
    imOpen=[]
    imgFoto=[]
    resized = []
    #get the directory with the images from the user
    data = os.listdir()
    print(data)
    cd = input("change directory to:   ")

    while cd != "x":
        
       
        os.chdir(cd)
        data = os.listdir()
        print(data)
        cd = input("change directory to:   ")

    #end

    #creating button for next image
    nxt=Button(root,text=">",command= Next)
    #creating button for previous image
    prvs=Button(root,text="<",command= Previous)
    photoButtons = []
    show_images()

    root.mainloop()
```

the idea is that the user should choose a directory then after they pressed 'x' the program should call show_images, which should display all the images in that directory on a canvas with a scrollbar attached to it, the user should then be able to pick and choose between them, and also choose next and previous, however, the scrollbar doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you need `photolist.config(xscrollcommand=scrl.set)`. At least some examples I found have that kind of line.

Comment: your code has syntax errors (lines ending in `/`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect a scrollbar to a widget you must do two things: tell the widget which scrollbar to interact with (via `xscrollcommand` and/or `yscrollcommand`), and tell the scrollbar which widget to scroll (with the `command` attribute. You are neglecting to do the first part.

Add the following somewhere after creating the scrollbar:

```
photolist.configure(xscrollcommand=scrl.set)
```

Note: you don't need to go to the trouble of embedding a frame in the canvas if all you want to do is scroll some images. You can directly create images on the canvas. The advantage that the frame gives you is you can use `pack` so you don't have to calculate the coordinates of where to place the image, but it adds a lot of complexity. Since you're placing the images side-by-side, it's easy to compute the x/y coordinates for each image.

Comment: the / is when a line gets too long, its for a new line

Comment: thanks, your answer did it, sorry for taking so long before replaying, my computor broke :-(

Comment: @Cid-EL: the `/` is illegal syntax. the proper character is `\\`

Comment: oh, sorry Bryan, my mistake, il remember it sure enough ;-P